# Переменные в функции

Tags: переменные, javascript

```
var title = "external title";
function example(){
    title = "changing external title";
    alert(title);
    var title = "internal title";
}

example();
alert(title);
```

Почему "при запуске кода сгенерируются сообщения "changing external title", а затем "external title", показывающее, что внешняя переменная title не была изменена внутри функции. " Разве title внутри функции не глобальная?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, вы же пишите в последней строке **var title**, а интерпретатор - двухпроходной, сначала он ищет объявления типа **`function name(){}`**, **`var name`** в объявляемой области видимости и делает эти переменные локальными, а  потом исполняет код. Благодаря этому поведению можно писать

```
 function Foo() {
    console.log('Me not run');
 }
 function(){
   var a=[Foo,Bar];
   a[0]();
   function Foo() {
     console.log("Hello Foo");
   }
   function Bar() {
     console.log("Hello Bar");
   }
 }();
```

вас же не удивляет что Foo и Bar локальны для этой области видимости и что a[0] не undefined ?

единственное что нужно помнить, что если вы объявляете функцию, то она станет сразу определена, еще на первом проходе,  а если переменную, то правая часть объявления будет выполнена только во втором проходе.

Comment: А если бы var отсутствовал, но в качестве параметра был external(title), title стал бы локальной переменной ?

Comment: да, параметры тоже локальные, сейчас найду где прочитать про это.

Comment: Вот [это][1] почитайте

[1]:http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-2-variable-object/